# issue with moving expire or disabled ad objects

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to bulk move expired active directory accounts and I'm getting an error "cannot find object with identity "ad.object"". Is there another way to get around this?

```
$expiredUsers = Search-ADAccount -AccountExpired

foreach ($user in $expiredUsers) {

$userName = $user.Name
$userName | Move-ADObject -TargetPath 'OU=expired users,OU=Corporate,DC=Domain,DC=com'

}
```

and the error:

```
Move-ADObject : Cannot find an object with identity:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without that $userName part.

```
$expiredUsers = Search-ADAccount -AccountExpired

foreach ($user in $expiredUsers) {

$user | Move-ADObject -TargetPath 'OU=expired users,OU=Corporate,DC=Domain,DC=com'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would also think you could just pipe this into a single line.

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpired | Move-ADObject -TargetPath 'OU=expired users,OU=Corporate,DC=Domain,DC=com'
```